# Task not found in Gruntfile.js

Tags: gruntjs

I have created two tasks with grunt. I can run them individually if i remove one.
If I try to run `grunt cssmin` or `grunt uglify` then it shows the error "SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
Warning: Task "cssmin" not found. Use --force to continue"
Here is my gruntfile.js

```
module.exports = function(grunt){
grunt.initConfig({
    pkg: grunt.file.readJSON('package.json'),
    uglify:{
        my_target:{
            files: [{
                expand: true,
                cwd: 'js/',
                src: ['*.js','!*.min.js'],
                dest: 'js/'
                ext : '.js'
            }]
        }
    },
    cssmin:{
        my_target:{
            files: [{
                expand: true,
                cwd: 'css/',
                src : ['*.css','!*.min.css'],
                dest: 'css/',
                ext : '.min.css'
            }]
        }
    }
});

grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-cssmin');
grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-uglify');
```

};

Can anyone point out what i am doing wrong. Thanks.

Comment: Add this at the end of your  grunt file task.registerTask('default', ['cssmin', 'uglify']);

https://gruntjs.com/api/grunt.task

Comment: what is "task" in task.registerTask('default',['cssmin','uglify']). Can you explain?

Comment: not working. Still showing same error.

Comment: Have you try to run the task with «grunt» before: grunt.task.registerTask(...)